# Design of a function that modifies from 1-4 values of a register

Tags: c, gcc, microcontroller, variadic-functions

I'm writing a C program (library) to control an IC that performs voltage and current measurements - the [INA260 mfd by TI](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ina260.pdf). Part of this effort requires setting values in the ***Configuration Register***; these values control *how* the IC performs its measurements. The Configuration Register is 16 bits, and contains four (4) three-bit values (let's call them **tribbles**) that control key aspects of the measurements (ref Fig. 30 & Table 5 on p. 22 of the PDF for those interested).

My initial approach to setting values in the Configuration Register has been to create separate functions to modify each of the 4 tribbles. This works, but it doesn't *seem* particularly efficient to me. One alternative I've considered is use of a 'variadic' function as they can support a variable number of arguments. IOW, the user may wish to use **default** values for three of the tribbles, and therefore needs to change only one - **or** - he may wish to change two tribble values.  Fig. 30

As I started to write this function I realized it's not as *straightforward* as the examples for computing an average or sum of a set of numbers. Each tribble is defined by not only its value (0-7), but also its **position** in the Configuration Register.

I began researching possibilities for passing a **2x(1-4)** array, but search results suggested this was a *non-starter*...  then I hit on the idea of asking on SO, and here I am.

Given that all Configuration Register changes should be accomplished through a single function call, is there a way to accomplish that as a variadic function - or should I be looking at something else?

Comment: Variadic functions are difficult to work with in C.  You could just have a function that takes 4 `int` arguments and let the user specify `-1` or some other value for the nibbles that are not changing.  Or it might be more readable if you have a struct representing the settings (which might or might not match how they are encoded in the device), let the user modify it in whatever way they want, then have functions to read and write that struct from the device.

Comment: It's really useful to show your code instead of trying to describe it, especially when you're concerned / unsure about its efficiency. You could be worrying about nothing.

Comment: https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_INA260/blob/master/Adafruit_INA260.cpp they just have separate functions. Is it really worth it? Here https://github.com/ardnew/INA260-STM32-HAL/blob/master/INA260/ina260.c is a ready driver for stm32 HALs.

Answer (score 1):

> or should I be looking at something else?

I would just represent the intention of setting the default as just an invalid or sentinel value. Variadic functions are really hard and error prone, just a normal function.

> the user may wish to use default values for three of the tribbles, and therefore needs to change only one - or - he may wish to change two tribble values

Taking inspiration from https://github.com/thomoray/INA260/blob/master/INA260.h#L68 and from https://github.com/thomoray/INA260/blob/master/INA260.cpp , the user would:

```
union ConfigurationRegister {
    struct __attribute__((packed)) {
        uint16_t mode : 3;
        uint16_t ishct : 3;
        uint16_t vbusct : 3;
        uint16_t avg : 3;
        uint16_t : 3;
        uint16_t rst : 1;
    };
    uint16_t rawValue;
};

void changeConfigurationRegister(
       int8_t mode,
       int8_t ishct,
       int8_t vbusct,
       int8_t avg) {
    ConfigurationRegister reg = readConfigurationRegister();
    if (mode != -1) reg.mode = mode;
    if (ishct != -1) reg.ishct = ishct;
    if (vbusct != -1) reg.vbusct = vbusct;
    if (avg != -1) reg.avg = avg;
    return writeConfigurationRegister(reg);
}
```

And done - you have one function, and you can choose which settings stay. You can represent with `-1` a "no change" action. You can realize your intention with the call:

```
 changeConfigurationRegister(-1, -1, -1, 0b101)
```

Alternatively, you could just add bools, but that would be more parameters.

Do not overcomplicate that it needs to be. KISS, prefer it simple, understandable, easy to use, readable.

Comment: Might add an `enum` constant `NoChange`.